# Camera intent resultCode always return cancelled for Nougat

Tags: android, android-intent

When I am using camera intent in Nouget versions camera intent working perfectly.

My Problem: But **resultCode** (onActivityResult()) always return cancelled.

Note: Same code return result correctly in older versions. I am facing only in Nougat

**My code:**

```
    private void takePicture(Activity context) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        Uri photoURI = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");

            String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
            photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                    context.getPackageName() + ".provider",
                    file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "takePicture: ", e);
        }
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
        takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);          
        context.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

With help of this [tutorial](https://proandroiddev.com/sharing-files-though-intents-are-you-ready-for-nougat-70f7e9294a0b)

Comment: try providing write permission to photo URI

Comment: @Sanjeet tried just now.. code updated.. same result return :(

Comment: This is not tied directly to OS version. The camera app that you are using is what returns the result, not Android. Perhaps the camera app that you are using does not honor `content` `Uri` values for `EXTRA_OUTPUT` (though it should).

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this issue by removing android: launchMode = "singleInstance" in my AndroidManifest.xml.

This problem also occurred with ImagePicker plugin Crop plugin ...

I hope this will help somebody.